# passing sensitive information to Firebase Cloud Functions using parameters

Tags: firebase, https, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement my own way of resetting user password for my mobile app. I've come to an idea to use cloud functions as I don't want anything other than Firebase working with my app. The problem is I will need to invoke three cloud functions to reset user password. First one will contain only user's email, second will contain code obtained by user from his password reset email and his email to check if code is valid and third one will contain his email and new password to set from cloud function.

The problem arise when I think about ways to pass this information into cloud functions. I know I can use URL parameters or just send it using POST method. But package that I would like to use to communicate with cloud functions doesn't support any other option than passing URL parameters to cloud function. I know I can write my own HTTP request to pass information using post but I'm thinking if there is any problem with sending this information using URL parameters. It's all sent over HTTPS which should guarantee obscurity of this data. I know that it still can be logged on server, and I don't know if Firebase store logs of cloud function requests with full URL parameters part visible. If yes, it would be big security issue with my app.

So, there are my questions:

1. Is there a security issue with passing sensitive information through
   URL parameters?
2. Should I create my own solution using plain HTTP requests to pass sensitive information using POST?
3. Does anyone know if Firebase stores logs with visible URL parameters?
4. Is this even good idea to use cloud function for this matter? Maybe I should handle it differently?

Comment: Can't you use one of the client SDKs?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm using Flutter and the only available client SDK there is [cloud_function](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions) and I want to use it but I'm still thinking about possible security threats because from what I understand it passes parameters in URL to cloud function.

Comment: I think that using a Callable Cloud Function is the way to go.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So, will there be enough protection from Firebase side to ensure nothing like this can be a potential security threat?

Comment: By using the Cloud Functions Plugin for Flutter, if you call an HTTPS Callable Cloud Function [with parameters](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions#usage), these parameters will be encrypted through SSL.

Comment: Okay thank you. That's the answer i was looking for. :)

Comment: you can't use Callable Cloud Function if you wrote it using python or anything other than nodejs. Which is shame, because you can't authenticate that function.

Comment: Callable Cloud Function are the "solution" for those who write their function in Firebase nodejs , and all the rest of people - got nothing from google and can't authenticate a call because the js SDK won't work for a python function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer this question for future people like me:
like [Renaud Tarnec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371862/renaud-tarnec) said in his comment. SSL certificate by default ciphers all URL parameters. So it's safe to pass information this way. Firebase DOES NOT store logs with visible URL parameters when you call cloud functions. It only stores an ID of called function in your logs, so it's not a  security threat.